MS Access subform giving error "you cannot add a record because a record is required in table X
I have a form with a subform which I am trying to enter data into 2 tables: tblAnaesthesia and tblSamplesTissue. I have the autonumber primary key (called ProcRef) from tblAnaesthesia table which I am trying to add to the tblSamplesTissue table to a column called ProcRef using the subform. I set the master-child relationship in the form, and have two other master-child relationships between the subforms (animal ID and the date). There is a one-to-many relationship between the two forms in the Relationships view, with referential integrity checked. After entering the data into my main form I can see the row of data appear in the table tblAnaesthesia including the ProcRef. But once I try and enter data into the subform linked to tblSamplesTissue it tells me I can't add a record because a related record is required in tblAnaesthesia. But it is there!
What is wrong?

Make sure the parent form is saved before attempthing to enter data in a subform.

Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666241/you-cannot-add-or-change-a-record-because-a-related-record-is-required-in-table

This is a design not programming issue - there is no code to analyze and therefore question not appropriate for SO. Suggest you post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.
